# How to get the process name of a PID in FreeBSD?

Tags: c++, c, c++11, freebsd

I am trying to write a function which returns the parent process name,
if it is `bash`, then it should return `bash`.

```
const std::string &getParentProcessName() {
  static std::string name;
  auto ppid = getppid();
#ifdef __FreeBSD__
  // ?????
#else
 ...
#endif
  name = "unknown";
  return name;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [kinfo_getproc](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=kinfo_getproc&sektion=3&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD%2010.0-RELEASE) function

```
   pid_t pid = ...;
   struct kinfo_proc *proc = kinfo_getproc(pid);
   if (proc) {
     printf("Name %s\n", proc->ki_comm); 
     //ki_comm should be the program name
     //see the sys/user.h header file for other relevant fields.

     free(proc);
   }
```

See also the [libprocstat](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=libprocstat&sektion=3&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD%2010.0-RELEASE) functions for aquiring process information.

Answer (score 3):

To help future visitors who may find this question,

here is a solution which works on `Linux`, `FreeBSD`, `OS X`, `NetBSD` and `Windows`:

```
__attribute__((unused)) std::string *getFileContent(const std::string &file,
                                                    std::string &content) {
  std::ifstream f(file.c_str());

  if (!f.is_open())
    return nullptr;

  f.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
  auto len = f.tellg();
  f.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

  if (len != static_cast<decltype(len)>(-1))
    content.reserve(static_cast<size_t>(f.tellg()));

  content.assign(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(f),
                 std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());

  return &content;
}

const std::string &getParentProcessName() {
  static std::string name;
#ifdef _WIN32
  HANDLE h = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
  PROCESSENTRY32 pe;

  auto zerope = [&]() {
    memset(&pe, 0, sizeof(pe));
    pe.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);
  };

  zerope();

  auto pid = GetCurrentProcessId();
  decltype(pid) ppid = -1;

  if (Process32First(h, &pe)) {
    do {
      if (pe.th32ProcessID == pid) {
        ppid = pe.th32ParentProcessID;
        break;
      }
    } while (Process32Next(h, &pe));
  }

  if (ppid != static_cast<decltype(ppid)>(-1)) {
    PROCESSENTRY32 *ppe = nullptr;
    zerope();

    if (Process32First(h, &pe)) {
      do {
        if (pe.th32ProcessID == ppid) {
          ppe = &pe;
          break;
        }
      } while (Process32Next(h, &pe));
    }

    if (ppe) {
      char *p = strrchr(ppe->szExeFile, '\\');
      if (p) {
        name = p + 1;
      } else {
        name = ppe->szExeFile;
      }
    }
  }

  CloseHandle(h);

  if (!name.empty()) {
    return name;
  }
#else
  auto getName = [](const char * path)->const char * {
    if (const char *p = strrchr(path, '/')) {
      return p + 1;
    }
    return path;
  };
  (void)getName;
  auto ppid = getppid();
#ifdef __APPLE__
  char path[PROC_PIDPATHINFO_MAXSIZE];
  if (proc_pidpath(ppid, path, sizeof(path))) {
    name = getName(path);
    return name;
  }
#elif defined(__FreeBSD__)
  struct kinfo_proc *proc = kinfo_getproc(ppid);
  if (proc) {
    name = getName(proc->ki_comm);
    free(proc);
    return name;
  }
#else
  std::stringstream file;
  file << "/proc/" << ppid << "/comm";
  if (getFileContent(file.str(), name)) {
    if (!name.empty() && name.rbegin()[0] == '\n') {
      name.resize(name.size() - 1);
    }
    return name;
  } else {
    file.str(std::string());
    file << "/proc/" << ppid << "/exe";
    char buf[PATH_MAX + 1];
    if (readlink(file.str().c_str(), buf, sizeof(buf)) > 0) {
      buf[PATH_MAX] = '\0';
      name = getName(buf);
      return name;
    }
  }
#endif
#endif
  name = "unknown";
  return name;
}
```